# Long Term Storage of D-Cell Battery

Tags: decomposition

I plan to store D-cell batteries in a winter home.  The shelf-life is finite: is there any reason not to freeze or refridgerate the batteries to extend the shelf life?

Comment: Freezing destroys the seal, so the battery dies rapidly after thawing. As for chilling, I've found no difference in shelf life (perhaps a *negative* effect from the dampness in the fridge).

Comment: D cells? That´s a bit 1990ies, isn´t it? ;)

Comment: There are different types; do you mean the old carbon/zinc s?

Comment: Shelf life of name brand batteries these days is a surprising number of years (Duracell, for example, claims 10 years). That said, I use a shelf in the fridge but that is as much because there is then one place in the house for them to be as anything else.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Freezing *might* destroy seals. Might as well not, depending on the type and brand. And the air in a fridge is surely not damp, but usually very *dry*. Things get damp in a fridge if you open the door too often in summer.

Comment: He says winter *home*. So I'd assume that he must leave minimal heat on to avoid freezing all sorts of things in the home; plumbing, drywall, can goods, and so on.